# Очистка большой таблицы ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Имеется таблица >20 млн. записей. Ее нужно как-нибудь быстро очистить. `TRUNCATE` не подходит так как у таблицы есть внешние ключи. `DELETE` выполняется более двух часов. Триггера все отключаю перед удалением. Есть ли варианты еще очистки таблицы без отключения внешних ключей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наиболее быстрым решением будет, перевести базу в simple recovery model, сделать disable индексов и констрейнтов + производить удаления в цикле пачками скажем по 10-100к, в зависимости от длительности, разделяя все паузами (`WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'`).

Comment: а в чем разница пачками или все сразу?

Comment: @mamuted разница в том что при этом подходе не блокируется таблица

Comment: @NickProskuryakov в смысле для предотвращения эскалации блокировки до уровня таблицы? тогда я бы порекомендовал автору дополнительно выключить эскалацию блокировки SET LOCK_ESCALATION = DISABLE, и ограничиться 5000 строками

Comment: @SergeNazarenko да, вы правы, именно для этого